# specific directory path using slash or dot slash (/ or ../) in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

Ok, this is very simple but I can't seem to figure it out.

I'm currently in (auth -> routes -> users.js) and I want to require a file from a directory in the root (routes -> index.js)

Obviously '...' is not how you do it. The flow of the directories is attached below the code.

```js
//authentication
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var userdata = require('../controllers/users');
var User = require('../models/users');

//require to lock routes from index.js 
require('.../routes/index.js');
```

[directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mld05.png)

Comment: When the file is called index you just need to require the directory.  var index = require('../routes');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`..` is up one level, so you need to combine two of those with a slash like so: `../../routes/index.js`

Comment: Awesome! thanks. I spend like 40 mins looking for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you use just `/foo/bar/bing` you'll be using the root of the file system. To go back you use `..`

So if you are in `Project/auth/routes` and want a file in auth, you'd use `../foo`, the root of the project, `../../bing`.

`..` means the parent directory and `.` means the current directory. You can chain them together all the way to the file system root.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot ! wasted incredible amount of time on trying to figure this simple thing out.